# Получить Instance уже созданного Диалога из Activity

Tags: android, java

Подскажите, как получить инстанс отображаемого диалога, имея ссылку на активити, на появление диалога я не могу повлиять поэтому ссылку на него передать не могу. Как его вытащить из родительской Активити?

Comment: Поясните ваш вопрос попонятнее, что именно вам нужно(какая задача кода)?

Comment: Есть отдельный поток, он имеет ссылку на текущую Activity, поток периодически запускает задачу сделать скриншот того что отображается не  экране в какой то момент в приложение запустило диалог (он отображается поверх нашей Activity) если мы вызовем что-то вроде activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getDrawingCache() то получим скриншот Без Диалога. Помимо всего перед скриншотом надо сделать кое какие преобразования с Диалогом, для этого нужно иметь ссылку на него. Вот я и спрашиваю как получить ссылку на текущий отображаемый диалог если к его созданию я не имею ни какого отношения

Comment: Вам нужно скриншот получать?

Comment: чувствую, что нужно использовать рутованные телефоны. Если я правильно помню, то так просто приложению не дают снимать скриншот. Но вот с компьютера снимать скриншот с подключенного устройства (с включенным debug) проще простого.

Comment: нет я когда-то находил библиотеку с похожим функционалом она не требовала рута и даже не нуждалась в дополнительных разрешениях. была написана на яве (без нативных вставок) но была обфусцирована. тем более я спокойно могу делать скриншот Activity потому что имею на нее ссылку. И вопрос изначально стоит получить ссылку на вновь появившийся диалог.

Comment: видимо нужно брать и смотреть библиотеку. Обсфуцированный код конечно неприятно, но для такой задачи думаю, вряд ли сильно помешает.

Comment: @killpackoff а если заприщена генерация drawingcache, то что вы получите? И пробовали ли просто получить кэш от getDecorView() ?

Comment: Я думаю,что вам просто надо программно вызвать свой кастомный диалог, и по завершению ввода данных нажать что-то вроде "ок", после чего обработать это нажатие с закрытие диалога и выполнения нужных вам операций. Как сделать кастомный диалог: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/126-urok-65-dialogi-alertdialog-kastomizatsija.html

И оброботчики диалога: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/127-urok-66-dialogi-obrabotchiki-i-operatsii.html

Сам пользуюсь.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK Еще раз повторю задача состоит именно в том чтобы достать чужой диалог! мои диалоги я и так контролировать могу.

Comment: @killpackoff http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android может поможет

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.

Answer (score 2):

В Android есть как минимум три способа создания диалоговых окон:

**1)** Используя класс **[Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)**. В таком случае жизненный цикл диалога зависит от активности и вообще принадлежит ей.

**2)** Используя класс **[AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)**. Ситуация такая же, как и с Dialog.

**3)** Создавая активность с темой

> `@android:style/Theme.Dialog.**`

В таком случае вы сможете управлять диалогом как полноценной активностью. Думаю, это ваш вариант.

Comment: Вопрос как раз таки в другом (я пишу библиотеку) и эти диалоги будут создавать другие разработчики и или сторонние SDK. я не имею доступа к созданию этих диалогов. у меня есть ссылка на Активити в отдельном потоке и если появился(или по таймауту проверять) какой нибудь диалог мне надо получить ссылку на него(диалог), для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: @killpackoff можно сделать так, чтобы создание диалогов было только через вашу библиотеку, тогда будет не трудно запоминать ссылки на диалоги. А также можно использовать DialogFragment.

Comment: К сожалению мне такой вариант не подходит, Потому что могут использоваться сторонние библиотеки которые производят диалоги в их код лезть нельзя, а обрабатывать нужно все диалоги...

В дебаге у WindowManager'а  (activity.getWindow().getWindowManager()) есть поле mGlobal в котором есть ссылки на все диалоги и активности... но достучаться до него из кода у меня не получается(поле приватное )...(Пробовал через рефлексию изменить доступ к полю но там также куча не доступных классов, и скаставать результат не получается, либо это будет слишком сложно и не правильно )

Comment: @killpackoff если использовать недокументированные методы, то нужно быть готовым поддерживать весь зоопарк телефонов и версий. Ведь каждый производитель может по своему изменять исходники.

Comment: поэтому я отказался от этой идеи и прошу помощи для нахождения нормального решения =)